# Passing parameter from vue to php error getting null!! via axios call

Tags: laravel, vuejs3

**chatcontroller.php**

```
public function CreateConversation(Request $req)
{
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    echo $req->to_id;
    conversation::create(
        [
            'user_id'  => $user_id,
            'user2_id' => $req->to_id,
        ]);
}
```

**Createconversation.vue**

```
<script>
export default{
components:
{
    AppLayout,
},
data()
{
    return{
       users: [],
       to_id: '',
    }
},

methods:
{
    
    CreateConversation(to_id)
    {
        this.to_id = to_id;
        console.log(to_id);
        axios.get('CreateConversation',{to_id: this.to_id,});
    }
}
}
</script>
```

**Web.php**

```
Route::get('/CreateConversation',[ChatsController::class,'CreateConversation']);
```

when i call createconversation from vue console.log the data correctly but in php it is null

error message: "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user2_id' cannot be null

why it is null i dont know help me out!! is the syntax wrong?

Comment: Did that console.log(to_id) show some value or its null?

Comment: yess it shows correct value i passed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending a **GET** request not a **POST** so try that.

```
public function CreateConversation($to_id)
{
    conversation::create(
        [
            'user_id'  => auth()->user()->id,
            'user2_id' => $to_id,
        ]);
}
```

Comment: yes that works perfectly can you explain? why get request deos not works?. thank you

Comment: If you use GET request then you don't need Request Object as an Argument to your method.

Comment: That **Request $req** is used when you have a POST request.

Comment: i'm enlighten by your knowledge thank you